# [iCloud] Синхронизация данных приложения на платформах iOS7 / iOS8

Tags: ipad, objective-c, ios, iphone, ios7

Приложение сохраняет свои данные по адресу ***ubiquitousDocumentsDirectoryURL***, т.е. адресс такого типа: ***file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/iCloud~com~company~App/Documents/***

**company**, **App** - относительные названия вместо реального названия фирмы и приложения.

Когда приложение сохранит данные, в бэкграунде iCloud Sync синхронизирует данные с сервером и другими устройствами, подписанными на этот же аккаунт.

Проект разрабатывается на iOS SDK 8.1, но минимальные требования стоят iOS 7.1.
Проблема заключается в следующем (п.2, п.3):

1. На устройствах, в которых платформа iOS 8, приложение видит файлы, хранящиеся на iCloud. Т.е. синхронизация данных между устройствами происходит успешно.
2. На устройствах с iOS 7 (если зайти  в настройки -> iCloud -> Хранилище и копии -> Хранилище, есть список приложений, которые хранят свои данные) показывает, что приложение использует iCloud, занимаемое место под данными, но не отображает список файлов.
3. Если запустить приложение под платформой iOS 7, и попытаться получить данные, то результат неуспешен, т.к. iCloud Sync не синхронизировал данные в папку (указана в начале вопроса).

P.S. [Либа](https://github.com/iRareMedia/iCloudDocumentSync#swift-projects-setup), которую использую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С новой системой, когда Apple ввели iCloud Drive, у всех перестал толком работать iCloud предыдущих версий. Решено [ЗАБИТЬ](http://www.tuaw.com/2014/09/17/psa-do-not-upgrade-to-icloud-drive-during-ios-8-installation/) на поддержку iOS 7.